# GridView is not adding rows to collection

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I`m developing WPF application based on MVVM.
I need to create DataGrid with 2 ComboBox columns.

I created the next grid:

```
 <DataGrid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="0,8,20,8" CanUserAddRows="True" CanUserDeleteRows="True"  ItemsSource="{Binding MapsGrid}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Main Category" Width="*">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox
                ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.MainCategories, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
                DisplayMemberPath="Category"
                                SelectedItem="{Binding DataContext.MainCategorySelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Sub Category" Width="*">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox
                ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.SubCategories, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
                DisplayMemberPath="Category"
                                  SelectedItem="{Binding DataContext.SubCategorySelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
                                />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>

        </DataGrid>
```

The grid looks exactly like I need and the ComboBox controls contains data but I don`t know why the grid not insert new rows to my collection.

In my view model I have the next collection:

```
     private ObservableCollection<MapsDescGridModel> _mapsGrid;
            public ObservableCollection<MapsDescGridModel> MapsGrid
            {
                get { return _mapsGrid; }
                set
                {
                    if (Equals(value, _mapsGrid)) return;
                    _mapsGrid = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("MapsGrid");
                }
            }
```

I initiliaze it in my constructor and I'm seeing a blank row in my datagrid but I can't add rows (I`m trying with Enter key)

The object "MapsDescGridModel" contains 2 entities (Entity framework entities)

```
 public class MapsDescGridModel: NotificationObject
    {
        public MapsDescGridModel()
        {

        }

        public MapsDescGridModel(MainCategories mainCat, SubCategories subcat)
        {
            MainCategory = mainCat;
            SubCatergory = subcat;
        }

        private MainCategories _mainCategory;
        public MainCategories MainCategory
        {
            get { return _mainCategory; }
            set
            {
                if (Equals(value, _mainCategory)) return;
                _mainCategory = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("MainCategory");
            }
        }


        private SubCategories _subCatergory;
        public SubCategories SubCatergory
        {
            get { return _subCatergory; }
            set
            {
                if (Equals(value, _subCatergory)) return;
                _subCatergory = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("SubCatergory");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I tried to add columns by code but I can see only one row (all the rest are copy of this row).
[image: All my rows are copy of one row]
[image: blank row at start]

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DataGridColumns wont be added to the visual tree. Thats why bindings which use the vt (e.g. ElementName, FindAncestor bindings) don't work there.
This problem look similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15883062/observablecollection-with-inotifypropertychanged-into-datagridcomboboxcolumn-bin) one.

Btw.: How does it make sense to bind the SelectedItem of each row to your main DataContext if there are many rows but only one DataContext? You should bind your SelectedItem of each row to a property in your `MapsDescGridModel` class.

Comment: Yes, I`m seeing that my logic is wrong. I need to think about new design. Thanks for the clarification